# Checking if a number is palindrome

Tags: python-3.x, palindrome

I have this code for checking if a number is a palindrome and for some reason it returns false for number=1 even though it is palindrome. Why is that? The code works for other cases such as 12321.

```
def palindrome_integer(number): 

    if number != int:
        return False
    elif str(number) == str(number)[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Hey dude, you've got multiple answers, feel free to show your appreciation for the people who _volunteered_ to help you by accepting one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def palindrome_integer(number):
    return type(number) == int and str(number)[::-1] == str(number)
```

Don't hesitate to comment if you have problem in understanding the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if `number` is integer, you should use `isistance`.

```
def palindrome_integer(number): 

    if not isinstance(number, int):
        return False
    elif str(number) == str(number)[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The rest of your code seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
return isinstance(n, int) and str(n) == str(n)[::-1]
```

Or slightly more contrived:

```
import re
x = str(n)
return re.match(r”\d+“, x) and x == x[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

solution without string

```
def palindrome_integer(num):
    copy = num
    rev = 0
    while num!= 0:
        rev = rev*10+num%10
        num = num//10
    return rev == copy
```